# Bad Google Postmaster Domain Reputation

Tags: email, gmail, spf, google-postmaster

One of our client's domains, healthhunt.in is experiencing issues with Gmail marking their emails as spam.
This issue does not exist with any other email provider, which we have verified via glockapps.com.

We have SPF, DKIM, and DMARC properly configured on the domain, however SPF is still showing a 0% success rate on Postmaster:

[image]

[image]

We're not sure if it's related to our bad domain reputation, however we would ideally like to resolve both issues.

[image]

Has anyone had any experience in resolving domain reputation issues with Google?

Comment: I'm dealing with exactly this problem. Postmaster tools is incredibly coarse, buggy and inconsistent, which makes it very hard to diagnose where the problem is. I'm getting bad reputation issues at the same time as having no recorded spam reports; these two things can't be true at the same time! Feedback ID doesn't work either. Gmail's spam filters are also very poor - even if you add an inbound address to your address book, and consistently move messages out of your spam folder, it will just keep putting them in there. Meanwhile, actual spam has no problem reaching the inbox.

Comment: @Synchro Yeah we're also not seeing any email deliverability issues or spam reports on Postmaster, so kind of at a loss as to how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that the spf record for your root domain name doesn't look quite right.

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:customeriomail.com
```

Normally, with SPF there should be a ~all or -all policy at the end. I'd recommend putting ~all at the end as it's softfail as opposed to -all which is hardfail. It's best to at least start with ~all.

This would be your corrected SPF record:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:customeriomail.com ~all
```

BTW, where you'd get include:customeriomail.com? I ask as i've not heard of them.

Note: Google Postmaster doesn't start showing results until you've sent quite a large volume.

And did you implement DKIM and DMARC as well?

Comment: Thanks for the SPF fix!
We use customer.io for our transactional email to customers.